# Nexus 4 API 22 emulator show white screen using media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Here is my code:

[image]

It works fine with Pixel 2 API 29,30, but crashes with Nexus 4 API 22.

On Nexus 4 screnn I see white screen and after some runs it makes strange noises like tc tc tc tc tc. Dunno how to describe that.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can run the media play on an emulator that far back. Try using a real device.

Comment: On real device everything ok. But there is 30 API version. I wanna test it on API 22.